# Google map some markers aren't showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a problem where only some markers are showing and not others.

I have a bunch of "tree_markers" that aren't showing.  Only the tree markers show which have the same name.

The live test page is here:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/widget.php?height=500&width=500&hike_id=108&type=hike

Would anyone know why the only tree markers that show up are "Eucalyptus" trees and not "Madron" or "Cypress"

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting the `tree_markers[]` object, it appears that many trees have the same exact coordinates, so they overlap and you see only the topmost. More specifically, all your madrones are under an eucalyptus.

Trying this in the console:

```
tree_markers[0].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(37.809398,-122.47945))
```

Moves one madrone in the water, to prove it's always been there, just not visible.

Comment: I think what the map is doing is putting the trees on top of each other so one type is always over the next.  Strange why it does that.  They are supposed to be spread apart on the map. lol

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. Do you have firebug? It'll help you debugging your google maps applications.

Comment: You are supposed to see about 10 markers with trees.  Do you see that many?  I only see 5 which are for only one type of tree.

Comment: Total markers?  Or markers of trees?  If you mouse over any tree marker, is there one that says "Madrone" ? - thanks!

Comment: That was the original question.  There are supposed to be tree markers for 3 -different- trees.  But for some reason only one type of tree shows up :)